# Unresolved external (old compiler)

Tags: c, visual-c++, assembly, 16-bit

I'm trying to compile C program with ASM procedure. It should be 16-bit, so I'm using Visual C++ 1.0 and MASM 6.11.

ASM code:

```
.MODEL MEDIUM
EXTRN first:WORD, second:WORD, third:WORD
.CODE
_Add_Ext PROC FAR
    mov AX, first
    add AX, second
    mov third, AX
_Add_Ext ENDP
END
```

I've compiled it in .obj file

```
ml.exe -c -Cx -FoC:\prjcts\2_6\2_7.obj C:\prjcts\2_6\2_7.asm
```

and included in project.

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int first = 1, second = 2, third = 0;
void main (void)
{
    printf("\nBefore adding third = %d", third);
    Add_Ext();
    printf("\nAfter adding third = %d", third);
}
```

When I'm trying to compile it, it gives me:

```
Compiling...
c:\prjcts\2_6\2_6.c
Linking...

C:\PRJCTS\2_6\2_7.OBJ(C:\prjcts\2_6\2_7.asm) : error L2029: 'first' : unresolved external
C:\PRJCTS\2_6\2_7.OBJ(C:\prjcts\2_6\2_7.asm) : error L2029: 'third' : unresolved external
C:\PRJCTS\2_6\2_7.OBJ(C:\prjcts\2_6\2_7.asm) : error L2029: 'second' : unresolved external

LINK returned error code 2.
Creating browser database...
2_6.EXE - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

So it sees my `.obj`, understands what it is, but can't figure out to take variables from C code? I don't want to use inline assembler, but I tried it earlier, and it worked.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but when writing a question here which includes code, please don't *retype* the code as that might introduce unrelated errors that are distracting from your real problem (which have happened for you now). Instead copy and paste the code.

Comment: Why? I didn't retype it, I'm too lazy for that.

Comment: I fixed your question Anton, but I believe @JoachimPileborg was referring to the fact that you had `third = %d”` with a smartquote (curly quote) instead of a traditional double quote `"`. I had a feeling to that somehow the code provided had been partially edited by hand since only one such smart quote was present. Since you didn't claim your code wouldn't compile I modified your code by fixing the quote.

Comment: Thanks. I've re-wrote quotes in my code just in case, but in Win98 there should be nothing "smart", especially quotes.

Comment: I don't see how you're including the C program in your build from what you've shown. Is the compile/link output you show a result of the command line you are showing?

Comment: @lurker Looks like the old IDE output. I'm guessing he assembled the assembly file manually, and added the object file to the project? Hard to tell, but it had me curious too.

Comment: The problem may be an issue of segments. What model are you compiling your C++ code in? I never learned enough about segmentation to fully understand it, since I started programming after 32-bit was already mainstream. Could be something to check, though, if mksteve's answer still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You do know that Visual C++ 1.0 is 23 years old, right? As a rule of thumb, you should never use compilers older than yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a simple guess, it will be `C` name mangling.  An extern in C will tend to be pre-pended with _

```
EXTRN _first:WORD, _second:WORD, _third:WORD
```

Comment: Of course all references inside the assembler code would also have to have the prefix of _ as well. This does appear to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!
Maybe tha code was for Microsoft C or something like that, not for VC++ 1.0

This code works.

```
.MODEL MEDIUM
EXTRN _first:WORD, _second:WORD, _third:WORD
.CODE
_Add_Ext PROC FAR
    mov AX, _first
    add AX, _second
    mov _third, AX
_Add_Ext ENDP
END
```